# JavaFX HTMLEditor disable hyperlink redirection

Tags: java, javafx, webview, hyperlink, html-editor

Is there a way to prevent the URLLoader handler for hyperlinks in a JavaFX HTMLEditor?

I'm looking for a similar effect like the CSS tag `pointer-events: none;`

Or is it possible to remove the URLLoader EventHandler from the HTMLEditor?

[image: HTMLEditor view]

[image: view after clicking on hyperlink]

Comment: Try setting the CSS using `htmlEditor.setStyle("pointer-events: none;");`?

Comment: neither `pointer-events: none;` nor `-fx-pointer-events: none;` has an effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but this stopped the hyperlinks from my htmlEditor.

```
Node webNode = htmlEditor.lookup(".web-view");
WebView webView = (WebView) webNode;
webView.getEngine().setCreatePopupHandler((PopupFeatures config) -> null);
```